# Java: Writer.write() and Writer.append() are the same; why do they both exist?

Tags: java, writer

I've inherited some Java. I have lots of experience with other C-like languages, but I'm still fairly new to Java. In one function, my predecessor has used both the `write()` and `append()` methods of the `Writer` class, but I can't figure out why. And more generally, I can't figure out why both methods exist, because [Oracle's doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) says, *An invocation of this method of the form `out.append(c)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `out.write(c)`*. Why do both methods exist? Do I need to care?

Comment: well, welcome to java, where there are more than one way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because its authors decided to make [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) implement the interface [`Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html).

Comment: Well that explains why append() exists, but not why write() does :-P

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard The `Writer` class defines its own API.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer made me realize that I need to look at "All Implemented Interfaces" in Oracle's doc for the class, not just the methods that are implemented by the class directly. Just as you say, `Writer` inherits from `Appendable`. Thanks very much!

Comment: Any thoughts on why my predecessor would have called both methods on the same object, within a few lines of each other? Maybe a historical accident?

Comment: @GreatBigBore I'd like to think that he was messing with his successor :)